# accessing $(System.AccessToken) in yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline and a azure-pipelines.yml that drives my build, that requires a PAT in order for the build script to push artifacts using nuget, by using "nuget sources add.."
this works!
but my PAT is in the script, which is bad, and the PAT will eventually expire, so I'd much rather use $(System.AccessToken), but I can't get it to work, there seems a lot of related questions, but I simply don't understand what I'm not doing.

This is the working yaml (with fake PAT)

```
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.201'        
  - script: dotnet tool restore
    displayName: Install FAKE
  - script: nuget sources add -name "Kookerella2" -source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/..../index.json -username anything -password thisismypat
    displayName: nuget add source
  - script: dotnet fake build
    displayName: Run Build
```

and to use $(System.AccessToken)

I do this? replacing the hardcoded pat with an environment variable %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%
(you have to scroll to the far right to see)
but this fails!

```
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.201'        
  - script: dotnet tool restore
    displayName: Install FAKE
  - script: nuget sources add -name "Kookerella2" -source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Kookerella2/_packaging/Kookerella2/nuget/v3/index.json -username anything -password %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    displayName: nuget add source
  - script: dotnet fake build
    displayName: Run Build
```

Am I doing something stupid?

---

based on feedback I've tried to use

```
$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
```

this failed, (I'm pretty sure that script defaults to the command prompt).

I then tried

```
  - powershell: nuget sources add -name "Kookerella2" -source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Kookerella2/_packaging/Kookerella2/nuget/v3/index.json -username anything -password $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

which failed in the nuget push in the build with

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User '123a17e0-1d16-4a98-a124-435fda808ac6' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'AddPackage'. (DevOps Activity ID: 4CCE5D91-5279-4782-BF9F-00279A087C6E)).
```

I do have

"project collection build service (Kookerella2) -> Contributor"

set under my artifacts permissions

---

the solution is marked below.
Summary is...there is NOTHING wrong with the orignal YAML, %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN% is valid for a command prompt, and works...ONCE you "allow project scoped builds" in the permissions of the artifacts (see below).
Why? I have no clue....but thats a luxury.

Comment: The `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` should be the correct value. So I agree with DSpirit`s answer. BTW, we could define a variable to storage the PAT, then define the variable in the Variables and set it as secret. Then we could use it in the build task. But just as you said, PAT will eventually expire.

Comment: I think its a command prompt, so that failed

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This should be due to the use of commandline. My suggestion is that use powershell task instead of command line task. Obviously you have already done this. For your second error, I provided an answer, you could check if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> which failed in the nuget push in the build with Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden

To resolve this issue, you could try to check if you have permission for `Your project Build Services`. By default, when you create a Feed over Artifacts on your AzureDevOps project, it's only have permission for `Project collection Build Service` but not for `your project Build Services`:

[image]

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/795493/403-error-during-nuget-restore.html) for some more details.

Comment: now that seemed to work! Can you add some detail about what it actually means? (I used TFS many many years ago, and abandoned it in favour of Jenkins, because of its labyrinthine security model made doing anything virtually impossible, I've deliberately adopted a "build server just runs build scripts" mentality...but that means I have to understand how to control the nothing else, but the permissions on the build agent)

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, This is because when we run the pipeline, the system will use the build service account to run the pipeline, so we need to ensure that this account has sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

With this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment

I assume you have a PowerShell script running as default on a windows machine. So you should access your variable as follows:

```yaml
 - script: nuget sources add -name "Kookerella2" -source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Kookerella2/_packaging/Kookerella2/nuget/v3/index.json -username anything -password $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
```

Comment: "The script keyword is a shortcut for the command-line task. The task runs a script using cmd.exe on Windows and Bash on other platforms." so no, I don't thnk so, and I don't know how to change it, ideally it would just work